# How to Upload Profile Picture with my REST API in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4

Hello I add one custom attribute of profile_picture to save the profile picture of customer but when i try to call the http://domain.com/ecommerce_app/rest/V1/customers API with following JSON Request:

```
{
 "customer": {
     "email": "abc1@gmail.com",
     "firstname": "Abc",
     "lastname": "Xyz" ,
     "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "profile_picture",
        "value": {
            "base64EncodedData": "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",
            "type": "image/png",
            "name": "new_image.png"
        }
      }
    ]

 },

 "password": "Abc@123456"
}
```

I got the following error:

```
{"message":"Error occurred during \"custom_attributes\" processing. Attribute \"profile_picture\" has invalid value. The \"array\" value's type is invalid. The \"string\" type was expected. Verify and try again."}
```

Please help me how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message posted, it looks like the customer attribute you created **"profile_picture"** accepts only **"string"** value, but you are passing an **array** of values. Try passing the value field with string as shown below.

```
{
 "customer": {
   "email": "abc1@gmail.com",
   "firstname": "Abc",
   "lastname": "Xyz" ,
   "custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "profile_picture",
      "value": "new_image.png"
    }
   ]
},
"password": "Abc@123456"
}
```

Comment: But in magento2.3 Customer REST API we need to upload image base64 code instead of image file